# Trouble with "Do you want to continue?" type cases in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

Here's the scenario:

I have a function in which the user is asked for an input - to select *m* items from a list of *n* items (given *m* <= *n*). FYI, he may input a wrong value if he'd like, in which case he'd be asked if he'd want to start over, but if he input the right one, it's all OK. I am stuck with the former part.

Here's my code, and I know it's wrong, so no need to penalize me!

```
column_names = ["DWUXZ", "bKDoH", "erLlI", "QJAfR", "dAfNn", "kpwGt", "fuDmY", "WoTau", "qrFaZ", "ZGSkx"] #The list to choose the items from

def newfunc():

    print (f"Here is the list of columns to choose from: {column_names}\n"
    args = input ("Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).\n").split(',')

    userinputs_notfound = [] #This will hold the wrong entries entered by the user.
    for arg in args:
        if arg.replace(" ", "") not in column_names:
            userinputs_notfound.append(arg.replace(" ", ""))
    
    if len(userinputs_notfound) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        while input("Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: ").lower() == 'y':
            newfunc() #Recursively calling the function

newfunc() #Calling the function.
```

I am not able to get the *while* part right. In short, here's what I'd like it to do:

1. User is given the option to select the strings from the given list (called *column_names*)
2. He enters the wrong values deliberately
3. The scripts says "*These entries weren't found. Would you like to try again? [Y/n]*"
4. When the user hit Y, it goes back and does this whole thing again.
5. If he selects *No*, it exits the loop

For the life of me, I am not able to get this right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some refactoring with your code:

(Solved the 'enter to select all columns' issue too.)

```
# The list to choose the items from
column_names = ["DWUXZ", "bKDoH", "erLlI", "QJAfR", "dAfNn", "kpwGt",
                "fuDmY", "WoTau", "qrFaZ", "ZGSkx"]

def get_input():
    print(f"Here is the list of columns to choose from: {column_names}\n")
    args = input("Enter column names separated by comma "
                  "(Hit enter to select all columns).\n").strip().split(',')
    return args


while True:
    args = get_input()
    if len(args) == 1 and args[0] == '':  # pressed enter
        print('OK. Selected all columns')
        break

    # This will hold the wrong entries entered by the user.
    userinputs_notfound = []
    for arg in args:
        if arg.replace(" ", "") not in column_names:
            userinputs_notfound.append(arg.replace(" ", ""))

    if not userinputs_notfound:
        print('OK')
        break

    should_quit = input("Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: ").lower() == 'n'
    if should_quit is True:
        break
```

Outputs:

```
Here is the list of columns to choose from: ['DWUXZ', 'bKDoH', 'erLlI', 'QJAfR', 'dAfNn', 'kpwGt', 'fuDmY', 'WoTau', 'qrFaZ', 'ZGSkx']

Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).
DWUXZ, bKDoH
OK
```

```
Here is the list of columns to choose from: ['DWUXZ', 'bKDoH', 'erLlI', 'QJAfR', 'dAfNn', 'kpwGt', 'fuDmY', 'WoTau', 'qrFaZ', 'ZGSkx']

Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).
fda, fdax
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: n
```

```
Here is the list of columns to choose from: ['DWUXZ', 'bKDoH', 'erLlI', 'QJAfR', 'dAfNn', 'kpwGt', 'fuDmY', 'WoTau', 'qrFaZ', 'ZGSkx']

Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).
fda, dax
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: y
Here is the list of columns to choose from: ['DWUXZ', 'bKDoH', 'erLlI', 'QJAfR', 'dAfNn', 'kpwGt', 'fuDmY', 'WoTau', 'qrFaZ', 'ZGSkx']

Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).
```

```
Here is the list of columns to choose from: ['DWUXZ', 'bKDoH', 'erLlI', 'QJAfR', 'dAfNn', 'kpwGt', 'fuDmY', 'WoTau', 'qrFaZ', 'ZGSkx']

Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).

OK. Selected all columns
```

Comment: Ha to tweak this a bit, but got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The entire body should be in a while loop that you break out once the input is correct. Don't use recursion in an unbounded fashion like this.

```
column_names = set(["DWUXZ", "bKDoH", "erLlI", "QJAfR", "dAfNn", "kpwGt", "fuDmY", "WoTau", "qrFaZ", "ZGSkx")

def newfunc():

    while True:
        print (f"Here is the list of columns to choose from: {column_names}\n"
        args = input ("Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).\n").split(',')
        if all(arg.replace(" ", "") in column_names for arg in args):
            break
           
        missing = set(args) - column_names
        if missing:
            print(f"Missing: {missing}")
            response = input("Do you want to try again?")
            if response.lower() == "n":
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
column_names = ["DWUXZ", "bKDoH", "erLlI", "QJAfR", "dAfNn", "kpwGt", "fuDmY", "WoTau", "qrFaZ", "ZGSkx"]

def newfunc():

print (f"Here is the list of columns to choose from: {column_names}\n") //correction
args = input("Enter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all columns).\n").split(',')

userinputs_notfound = [] #This will hold the wrong entries entered by the user.
for arg in args:
    if arg.replace(" ", "") not in column_names:
        userinputs_notfound.append(arg.replace(" ", ""))

if len(userinputs_notfound) == 0:
    pass
else:
    if input("Do you want to continue? [Y/n]: ").lower() == 'y': //correction no need of while
        newfunc()

newfunc() #Calling the function.
```

Comment: everything was perfect remove while and write if condition

Answer (score 0):

Either put the whole body of function within the for loop, and leave out the recursive call as:

```
def foo():
    while x:
        do_stuff
        change_x
```

or leave out while loop and keep the recursion with a conditional if statement as:

```
def foo():
    do_stuff
    if condition:
        foo()
```

Otherwise you keep calling the function and so you need to escape each `while input() == 'y'` loop that you have created during the run of the program, however many that might be.

As for 'hit enter to keep select all columns:

```
if arg == ['']:
    arg = column_names
```

Check against `['']` because you split your user input.

Answer (score 0):

This one is for python 3.8+

```
# The list to choose from
col_names = ["DWUXZ", "bKDoH", "erLlI", "QJAfR", "dAfNn", "kpwGt", "fuDmY", "WoTau", "qrFaZ", "ZGSkx"]

def newFunc():
    # Print all the available column names.
    print("List of columns to choose from:\n", *col_names, sep = '\n')

    # Filter out the missing names (if any) and ask for the prompt.
    # The anonymous function inside lambda match against the empty
    # string when the user chooses to select all.
    while missing := list(filter(lambda name: name and name not in col_names,
    input("\nEnter column names separated by comma (Hit enter to select all): ").split(','))):
        
        print("Missing:", *missing, sep = '\n')
        # Break the loop for any of the negetive response.
        if input("\nDo you want to continue? ").lower() in ['n', "no", "nope", "nah"]:
            break

    # Implement here your logic when no missing is found.


# Call the function.
newFunc()
```

With the help of assignment operator `:=` we did this within few lines of code.